# Populating android spinner with dynamic array name

Tags: android, dynamic, spinner

i want to do something like this,Plz help me

```
    Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner5
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
            this,**R.array.country_array**, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter5);
```

i need to make R.array.country_array to be dynamic for example to change country_code to another array name like city_array or like stat_array.

i tried to write "R.array."+dynamic_variable_array_name

but i failed..any help

Answer (score 5):

Why don't you initialize your array **before** you refer it to the ArrayAdapter?

```
Array myArray = getMyArray();

ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
            this, myArray, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
```

[Update]
Ok, i've just noticed `ArrayAdapter.createFromResource` doesn't work with non-resources. But this will work:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, myArray);
```

Comment: the first option works for me. only that i declare myArray as an int like this:
    int myArray = R.array.my_array_name; ArrayAdapter<CharSequence>adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, myArray, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
Spinner countrySpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.search_country);
CharSequence[] myArray = new CharSequence[]{
                "Qatar","UAE","India","America"
        };
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> countryAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,myArray);
        countryAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
countrySpinner.setAdapter(countryAdapter);
```